# Every probability measure over countable sample space follows form of discrete measure.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

## Context

The triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is a probability space with:

- Sample space $\Omega$ - which is a set,
- $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ which is a set of subsets of $\Omega$ that has the following properties:

  1. $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$,
  2. $A \in \mathcal{F} \implies A^c = \Omega \backslash A \in \mathcal{F}$,
  3. The sequence $(A_k)_{k = 1}^\infty \subseteq \mathcal{F} \implies \bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty A_k \in \mathcal{F}$
- Probability measure $\mathbb{P} : \mathcal{F} \to [0,\infty)$ where

  1. $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) = 1$,
  2. $\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(A_k)$ where the $A_k$ are mutually disjoint.

An event space is a probability space without the probability measure, i.e: $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$.

I'm considering a specific probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{P}(\Omega), \mathbb{P})$ where
$$\mathbb{P}(A) := \sum_{\omega \in A}\rho(\omega)\qquad (A \subseteq \Omega)$$
where $\rho : \Omega \to [0,1]$ is any function such that $\sum_{\omega \in \Omega}\rho(\omega) = 1$. It is not hard to prove that $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure. Here, the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ is called the discrete probability measure.

## The Problem

I'm trying to prove that if $\Omega$ is countable, then the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{P}(\Omega), \mathbb{P})$ will have its probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ always be in the form of the discrete probability measure as detailed in the context, regardless of its concrete definition.

## What I've Tried

Given that $\Omega$ is countable, we can assign probabilities to all the singleton sets. This is because if we let $S$ be the collection of these singleton sets $S = \{\{\omega\}: \omega \in \Omega\}$, we have $\bigcup_{X \in S} X = \Omega$. So this implies
$$1 = \mathbb{P}(\Omega) = \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{X \in S} X\right) = \sum_{X \in S}\mathbb{P}(X)$$
With the last part of the equality holding because all the $X$s are mutually disjoint. However, since each $X$ simply has one element in it, we can use the axiom of choice(?) to make it such that we can define $\rho$ such that $\rho(x) = \mathbb{P}(X)$ where $x \in X$ is the only element in $X$.

From here we can see that $\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} \rho(\omega) = \sum_{X \in S}\mathbb{P}(X) = 1$. Therefore $\mathbb{P}$ is a discrete probability measure, as required.

Have I made any mistakes with my proof? If so, how can I correct them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are already given $(\Omega, \mathcal{P}(\Omega), \mathbb{P})$. You can just define $\rho (\omega)=\mathcal P (\{\omega\})$. There is no need for Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Your proof is ok.

Comment: I'm confused about the line "Given that $\Omega$ is countable, we can assign probabilities to all singleton sets."  What if $\mathcal F$ doesn't contain any singletons?

Comment: @user6247850 what I can do is pick out individual elements $a,b,c,d,\dots$ and then put them into their own sets $\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{d\},\dots$. I then collect all of these singleton sets into $S$, and generate a $\sigma$-algebra out of it $\mathcal{F} = \sigma(S)$. By definition, $\mathcal{F}$ contains any combination of countable unions, intersections, and complements. So $\mathcal{F}$ contains more than just singleton sets. The proof still works as normal since each singleton set is mutually disjoint with each other, so you can add their probabilities together.

Comment: @Kookie Okay, so you are assuming $\mathcal F = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, not $\mathcal F \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$?  Or you are assuming that $\mathbb{P}$ is defined on _every_ $\sigma$-algebra of $\Omega$, not just the one you started with in the probability space triple?

Comment: I've defined $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. $\mathbb{P}$ is defined specifically over the space $(\Omega, \mathcal{P}(\Omega), \mathbb{P})$, which $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{\Omega})$ can be generated by an appropriate $\sigma$-algebra of some set $S$.

Comment: @Kookie Oh, okay.  Sorry, I was going by what you wrote first in the question where you have $\mathcal F \subseteq \mathcal P(\omega)$ instead of $\mathcal F = \mathcal P(\Omega)$.  I didn't see that you changed it later.